# List each and every Folder and file

Tags: android, file

Plzzz help me with this. Already late searching for the solution:

I want to list each and every Folder and file which is in the Android Phone's Internal Memory and External Memory.

The below code only gets list of files in one single directory.. But I'm unable to understand how would I list all the folders and files from internal and external memory.

> .....  List files = getListFiles(new File("YOUR ROOT"));   ....
>   private List getListFiles(File parentDir) {
>       ArrayList inFiles = new ArrayList();
>       File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
>       for (File file : files) {
>           if (file.isDirectory()) {
>               inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
>           } else {
>               if(file.getName().endsWith(".csv")){
>                   inFiles.add(file);
>               }
>           }
>       }
>       return inFiles; }

Any help?

Comment: Are you making any progress?

Comment: Yes found the solution somewhere else...

Comment: It's best if you share your answer so people who run across your question will benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the File object.  It gives you methods to get all the files in a directory, tells you whether a file is a directory, and many other things.

You could easily do a recursive tree walk of the directory system.  You probably will run into permissions issues, though, unless you have "rooted" your device.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this somewhere else.. This is how it's done (fully functional code)

```
public void walk(File root) {

          File[] list = root.listFiles();

          for (File f : list) {
              if (f.isDirectory()) {
                  Log.d("realcrazy", "Dir: " + f.getAbsoluteFile());
                  walk(f);
              }
              else {
                  Log.d("realcrazy2", "File: " + f.getAbsoluteFile());
              }
          }

      }
```